# What size wire and breaker do I need for my shed/workshop?

Tags: circuit-breaker, subpanel, wire, shed, workshop

I am looking to run electricity to my shed and I am unsure of what size wire and breaker I need.

My main panel will be about 100ft away from my shed. My shed is 12X20 and I want to install 6-8 4ft 4 bulb fluorescent/LED lights, LED flood lights and about 8-10 receptacles. Two of the 4ft lights will be outside under the lean-to of my shed along with 2 of the receptacles.

I will be using table, miter, scroll and circular saws, a router, an air compressor, a shop vac, a grinder, an AC window unit, a shop fan/blower and plan on adding a CNC router, a dust collection system, a 60-80 gallon air compressor and possibly a welding machine on the exterior.

Of course I will not be using all these at the same time but I would rather do it right the first time.

Comment: What size is your existing electrical service?

Comment: Will any resident ever own an electric vehicle?

Comment: You're not looking to add "a breaker" - you're looking for a whole sub-panel! Keep in mind that you may need to supply 240v for the welder and possibly the CNC router, so you'll need extra space in the panel. As both Harper and TPE always say, it's cheaper to buy a lot of spaces now and not need 'em than to replace the panel later when you do need 'em.

Comment: Also, I know that "shopping recommendation" questions are off-topic (you didn't ask one), but I've got to say that I recently installed some LED shop lights from a store that gets their Freight at the Harbor ;). They're plug-in (not hard wired), but they are _fantastically_ bright at 5000 lumens each and I highly recommend them! They seem to have a slight flicker for the first minute or two when they're turned on, but it does go away. I don't know if they're rated for outdoor installation, though, so be aware of that.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have none in my shed at the moment. I am planning to put some soon. This is why I asked. I believe my main panel on the outside of my house is 200 AMP.

Comment: @Freeman I have a bunch of space on my main 200 AMP panel that is on the outside of my house. I'll add a subpanel instead of running more than one wire to my shed. What size wire would I have to run and what size breakers ? I know the 240V for the welder. I believe the CNC router is 120v.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're on the right track, then. I'll let the electricians answer those questions.

Comment: @johnnyserigny -- did you have a specific welder in mind, by the way? If so, can you give us make/model information on it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel-- No I am still undecided at the moment. I do a lot of my welding at work but I plan on buying one in the near future.

Comment: @johnnyserigny can you post photos of your main panel please, as well as how many square feet your house is?  I suspect that between the welder receptacle and the air compressor, this'll add up to a fair bit of load, unless you want to be stuck choosing between "welding" and "having anything else going on in the shop..."

Answer (score 2):

You will not be using everything all at the same time. So I would look at the nameplate Full Load Amps of your largest load, probably the table saw, plus any other things that might be running at the same time, such as the dust collector,  lights and if the compressor is on a demand pressure switch, add that too because it might come one without you turning it on. Then add another 25% for good measure.

Comment: Ok. I will look at all my tools and find that out. Thanks